# How to close a lightbox and go to #id on underlying page in one href

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

I have a page with a contact section (id: #contact) at the bottom of the page. On the same page I use a lightbox to display larger versions of some images. The contact section can be scrolled to by clicking the following button (displayed :

```
       <a href="#img3"><img src="img/event/bbq3small.jpg"></a>
       <div class="lightbox" id="img3">
        <figure><img src="img/event/bbq3.jpg" alt="医王山でバーベキューパーティー">
        <a href="#img4"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-lg next"></i></a>
        <a href="#img2"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg previous"></i></a>
        <a href="#_"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg exit"></i></a>
        <figcaption>医王山でバーベキューパーティー</figcaption>
        </figure>
       </div>

     <!-- Contact Button -->
           <div class="scroll-contact d-block">
           <a class="btn btn-contact js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
           </a>
           </div>

    .scroll-contact {
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1049;
      right: 2%;
      bottom: 2%;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px; }
      .scroll-contact .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 28px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 100%; }
        .scroll-contact .btn:focus {
          outline: none; }

.lightbox {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}

    .lightbox figure {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width:90%;
        max-width: 500px;}

    .lightbox img {
        width:100%;
        max-height: 500px;}

    .lightbox figcaption {
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
        color:white;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 5px;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}

    .next {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 2%;
        opacity: 0.9;
        color: white;}

    .previous { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 2%;
        opacity: 0.9;
        color: white;}

    .exit {
        position: absolute;
        top:2%;
        right:2%;
        color:white;}

    .lightbox:target {
        outline: none;
        display: block;}
```

This button remains visible even when the lightbox is displayed. How can I close the lightbox and scroll to the contact section from one click of the contact button? I'm using the #_ command to close the lightbox, but I don't know how to do both from the single button.

I should have added that I have a javascript file, sorry. Anyway, I incorporated the code you made (at the bottom of the file). Thanks so much. It works, but it has killed the smooth scroll function. How do I include it in your function?

```
(function($) {
  "use strict"; // Start of use strict

  // Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
  $('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 48)
        }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

  // Closes responsive menu when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });

  // Activate scrollspy to add active class to navbar items on scroll
  $('body').scrollspy({
    target: '#mainNav',
    offset: 54
  });

  // Collapse the navbar when page is scrolled
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#mainNav").offset().top > 100) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("navbar-shrink");
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("navbar-shrink");
    }
  });

  // Floating label headings for the contact form
  $(function() {
    $("body").on("input propertychange", ".floating-label-form-group", function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass("floating-label-form-group-with-value", !!$(e.target).val());
    }).on("focus", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
      $(this).addClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
    }).on("blur", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
      $(this).removeClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
    });
  });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict

function processAction(hideElemId, navElemId)
    {
        var elemToHide = null;

        try
        {
            // Hide the element with the specified id
            elemToHide = document.getElementById(hideElemId);
            elemToHide.setAttribute("style", "display:none"); 
            // Or alternatively, elemToHide.className = "(some class that hides element)";

            // Navigate to the element with specified id
            window.location.hash = navElemId;

        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert("processAction Error:  " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide all of what you have thus far (including html, javascript, etc.)?

Comment: Do you mean the entire html, css and javascript content?

Comment: At least the bare minimum in order to simulate your issue.

Comment: Is it enough now?

Comment: Is this custom coded lightbox? If you would use fancyBox, you would simply call `$.fancybox.close()` or you could just add `data-fancybox-close` attribute to your element and clicking it will close active instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a javascript function that is called when the 'Contact' button is clicked using something like

```
href="javascript: processAction('(hideElementId)','(navToElementId)')"

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function processAction(hideElemId, navElemId)
    {
        var elemToHide = null;

        try
        {
            // Hide the element with the specified id
            elemToHide = document.getElementById(hideElemId);
            elemToHide.setAttribute("style", "display:none"); 
            // Or alternatively, elemToHide.className = "(some class that hides element)";

            // Navigate to the element with specified id
            window.location.hash = navElemId;

        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert("processAction Error:  " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, basically you could change <a class="btn btn-contact js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact"> to <a href="javascript: processAction('img3','contact')">

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to work consistently. After clicking it once, it is no longer responsive (with no lightbox displayed). When the lightbox is displayed it seems fine.

Comment: Do you want to toggle the "lightbox"?  The logic is working as it should, but apparently, it isn't clear to me, what all you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issues I wish to solve are: 1) when jumping to the contact section, the smooth scroll no longer works (see JavaScript above: js-scroll-trigger). 2) If the lightbox is not displayed, clicking the contact button only works on the first instance. Scrolling away from the #contact section then clicking again does nothing. I'm not sure what's causing the button to become unresponsive though, because the first time it is clicked, it works fine. If the lightbox is displayed when the button is clicked, it jumps to the contact section every time as it should.

Comment: I've made the page available here: http://topenglish.sakura.ne.jp/test/event.html

Comment: I think there may be an issue with using <a href="javascript: processAction('img3','contact')">. The same contact button is shown for all images, so using and particular image as a parameter doesn't seem correct?

Comment: I had an idea. Can't I just add a new function to the javascript above, like this:  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {if lightbox display = block, set display to none}? I'm not sure how to do this though...

Comment: Are you trying to control the "toggling" of the lightbox elements using a scroll event? You could use the jQuery hide()/show() methods. e.g. - $('.lightbox').hide() and $('.lightbox').show(), although you may need to check the visible state of the elements with the lightbox class (perhaps using $('.lightbox').is(":visible")).  If so, you may be able to use your original nav approach to the 'contact' section OR remove the portion of my function that hides the single 'lightbox' element. Alternatively, the <a> href could be href="javascript: window.location.hash=contact", no need to use my func.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help codemaker.

In the end I came up with what seems to be a very simple solution. Although I'm not sure how correct it is. In my html I use #_ to close the lightboxes, so I added window.location="#_"; under the $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function()), which is called when the button linked to #contact is clicked. So I ended up with this:

```
<a class="btn btn-contact js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">

 // Closes responsive menu or lightbox when a scroll trigger link is clicked
  $('.js-scroll-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
      window.location="#_";
  });
```